# Como acessar os campos do json response no nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, express.js

Estou estudando um pouco sobre nodeJs e estou enfrentando dificuldades para capturar e acessar json response, Por exemplo: Meu GetByID

```
exports.getProduto = function(req, res) {
    const produtoId = req.params.id
    const queryString = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE idproduto = ?;"
       pool.query(queryString, [produtoId], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Erro: ' + err)
            res.sendStatus(500)
            res.end()
            return
        }
        console.log('SUCESSO!')
        res.json(rows)
    }) 
   }
```

Quando dou o get tenho essa resposta. Porem eu gostaria de acessar os dados(campos) do json  e eu não sei como eu faço isso.

```
[
{
    "idproduto": 1,
    "nome": "LANCHE",
    "preco": 20,
    "imagem": null
}
]
```

Comment: Como assim guardar os campos individualmente?

Comment: Tenta reformular a pergunta, talvez algo no sentido de retorno em json a partir de uma resposta do banco de dados, sua pergunta está mal formulada.

Comment: Acabei de mudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query(exemplo):

```
[
 {
    "idproduto": 1,
    "nome": "LANCHE1",
    "preco": 20,
    "imagem": null
 },
 {
    "idproduto": 2,
    "nome": "LANCHE2",
    "preco": 20,
    "imagem": null
 }
]

    rows[0].nome //output: LANCHE1
    rows[1].nome // output: LANCHE2
```

rows -> resultado da query
[0] -> linha que quero ver os dados
nome -> nome da coluna que quero o dado